# Updated e text editor. Now can't use it as default program

Tags: windows-vista, installation, e-texteditor

I'm running Vista, 64-bit. I recently updated e text editor. Great, I thought. It seems more stable, but has a huge flaw. I can no longer set it as the default programs for file types.

During installation, there is an option to use e as the default editor for `.txt` files, so was surprised to find that when I right-clicked on say, a `.php` file, it was not in the list of recommended programs, nor other programs.

I click the Browse button and select `e.exe` from my Program Files folder, but it has no effect.

Is there any way I can force vista to use C:/Program Files/e/e.exe as my default program for `.php` etc files? Is there a way I can add it to the list of recognized programs by Vista?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this one -> [change/force filetype associations](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/06/20/how-to-edit-or-change-file-type-or-extension-associations-default-programs-in-windows-vista/). If the default vista method doesn't help, then you should use [third party tools](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/06/20/windows-vista-file-associations-advanced-editing-management-tools/)

Comment: Thanks. Downloaded Creative Element Power Tools and it did the job flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Does [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6172036.html) help you at all Martin? Basically lists a few ways of setting the file association, I think Figure D is what you're looking for.

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6172036.html

Comment: Yeah. Tried that, no luck. The problem is, when a select the `.exe` and hit Enter, it just forgets the choice it seems.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:
https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6172036.html

If the program still doesn't open the file then its most likely a command line argument issue.  Im pretty sure only the developers could fix that.